# I am writing a bash script and I got stuck at a place where I am piping using the `jq` command

Tags: bash, shell, jq, aws-cli

My Input JSON:

```
{
    "PendingMaintenanceActions": [
        {
            "ResourceIdentifier": "arn:aws:rds:xxxxxx1230000345",
            "PendingMaintenanceActionDetails": [
                {
                    "Action": "hardware-maintenance",
                    "AutoAppliedAfterDate": "2020-12-17T08:00:00Z",
                    "ForcedApplyDate": "2020-12-18T13:00:00Z",
                    "CurrentApplyDate": "2020-12-17T08:00:00Z",
                    "Description": "Maintenance on the underlying hardware"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Required output:

```
arn:aws:rds:xxxxxx1230000345,hardware-maintenance,2020-12-17T08:00:00Z,Maintenance on the underlying hardware
```

I tried a lot but no luck. Can someone help me to get the required output.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify the specific problem you are having, e.g. by showing what you have tried, which might also help clarify your requirements. E.g., does the output have to conform to the CSV conventions?

Comment: @Kaylan : _I tried a lot but no luck_  ..... : I don't see any tries in your post. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aws rds ... | jq '.PendingMaintenanceActions[].ResourceIdentifier + "," + .PendingMaintenanceActions[].PendingMaintenanceActionDetails[].Action + "," + .PendingMaintenanceActions[].PendingMaintenanceActionDetails[].CurrentApplyDate + "," + .PendingMaintenanceActions[].PendingMaintenanceActionDetails[].Description'
```

Not sure which date is required but CurrentApplyDate can be changed if necessary